# Mostrar quanto custa no total

Tags: c#, winforms

Um programa no Windows Form que estou criando , quero ao clicar nos check dos alimentos escolhidos a barra de total deve mostrar quanto está ficando, mas sempre aparece em branco o que devo fazer?Segue o código do que eu fiz:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class FourCustomController : UserControl
    {
        float[] ValorProduto = new float[9];


        float somaTotal = 15;
        private string txtTotal;

        public FourCustomController()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }


         private void Salvar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void NaoNulo(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string caminho = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            File.WriteAllText(caminho, textBox2.Text)  ;
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValorProduto[0] = 15f;
            somaTotal += ValorProduto[0];
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValorProduto[1] = 16f;
            somaTotal += ValorProduto[1];
        }

        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValorProduto[2] = 17f;
            somaTotal += ValorProduto[2];
        }

        private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValorProduto[3] = 10f;
            somaTotal += ValorProduto[3];
        }

        private void checkBox5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValorProduto[4] = 12f;
            somaTotal += ValorProduto[4];
        }

        private void checkBox6_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValorProduto[5] = 16f;
            somaTotal += ValorProduto[5];
        }

        private void checkBox7_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValorProduto[6] = 5f;
            somaTotal += ValorProduto[6];
        }

        private void checkBox8_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValorProduto[7] = 7f;
            somaTotal += ValorProduto[7];
        }

        private void checkBox9_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ValorProduto[8] = 7f;
            somaTotal += ValorProduto[8];
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(String.Format("#{0}" , somaTotal));


        }

        private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa noite. Tentou depurar? Viu se o valor esta sendo atribuído.
Tenta utilizar o this.somatotal ao inves de somatotal.

Comment: Tentei sim, ele nao estava sendo atribuido, por conta disto o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limpei um pouco o seu código e otimizei alguns pontos:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class FourCustomController : UserControl
    {   
        float somaTotal = 15;

        public FourCustomController()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InicializaControls();
        }

        private void InicializaControls()
        {
            checkBox1.Tag = 15f;
            checkBox2.Tag = 16f;
            checkBox3.Tag = 17f;
            checkBox4.Tag = 10f;
            checkBox5.Tag = 12f;
            checkBox6.Tag = 16f;
            checkBox7.Tag = 5f;
            checkBox8.Tag = 7f;
            checkBox9.Tag = 7f;

            textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", 0);
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void Salvar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void NaoNulo(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string caminho = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            File.WriteAllText(caminho, textBox2.Text);
        }

        private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var checkBox = sender as CheckBox;

            if(checkBox != null && checkBox.Tag != null)
                SomaTotal((float)checkBox.Tag, checkBox.Checked);
        }

        private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void SomaTotal(float valor, bool blnEntrada)
        {
            if(blnEntrada)
                somaTotal += valor;
            else
                somaTotal -= valor;

            textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", somaTotal);
        }
    }
}
```

Para que esta solução funcione, deve definir o evento `checkBox_CheckedChanged` em todas as `CheckBox` da mesma forma, ou seja, quando o valor de qualquer uma das `CheckBox` for alterado o método evocado deve ser sempre o mesmo, porque faz o mesmo procedimento para todas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nossa, demais !! funcionou muito bem , eu havia tentado antes de testar seu codigo com  todos no CheckedChanged e n tinha ido , mas agora realmente com essa melhora na logica e sintaxe funcionou corretamente, obrigado mesmo, estou começando em WF e estava estudando algumas coisas ,

Comment: De nada! Aproveite e dê um UP na resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Você fez um `TextChanged` para seu `textBox1`, mas ele nunca terá o texto mudado já que está `Enable = false`.

Estou me referindo a esse trecho, onde textBox1.Text só recebe o valor do `SomaTotal` se o evento `TextChanged` ocorrer:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(String.Format("#{0}" , somaTotal));
}
```

Ao invés disso faça a atribuição aqui:

```
private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(String.Format("#{0}" , somaTotal));
    MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
}
```

No entanto seu código tem mais problemas. Sua soma acontece sempre que o `checkbox` muda, não importa se ele está selecionado ou não.

Se ele foi selecionado deve somar e se foi retirado subtrai, caso contrário o valor mostrado ficará errado.

Aparentemente você está usando essa aplicação pra estudar, tente ler com atenção tudo que está no seu código e utilize o **Debugging**, irá ajudar no seu aprendizado.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, realmente estou usando para estudar, foi minha primeira aplicação em WF e queria testar algumas coisas.